# Hex to Binary Angle Measurement (BAMS) in any language

Tags: binary, hex, data-conversion

I have a 32-bit hex value, for example `04FA4FA4` and I want to know how to convert it to [BAMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling) in the form of a double. An example in any language would work fine, I am only concerned about learning the algorithm or formula to make the conversion. I know how to convert to BAMS when I have a form like, `000:00.0000` but I can't figure out how to make the conversion from Hex.

Comment: To clarify, you want to convert a hexadecimal string to a float?

Comment: @Magtheridon96 I am trying to get to a double, but if someone can help me with the algorithm I can take steps to change data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://www.globalspec.com/reference/14722/160210/Chapter-7-5-3-Binary-Angular-Measure) is the easiest to understand resource I found. The algorithm is simple:

```
(decimal hex value) * 180 / 2^(n-1)       //where n is the number of bits
```

The example in the reference is,

```
0000 0000 1010 0110
 0    0    A    6
166 * 180 * 2^−15 = 0.9118 degrees
```

The code for this algorithm is so simple, I don't think I need to enumerate it here. Let me know, if someone feels this is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure that division sign is in the correct place. I have:
(decimal hex value) * 180 * 2^(n-1) = degrees, i.e.:
(decimal hex value) = degrees / 180 * 2^(n-1)

Thanks for the helpful post!